# None, None, etc in a list comprehension printing

Tags: list, printing, append, list-comprehension

can somebody explain me that?:

```
a = []
[a.append(i) for i in range(0, 4)]
print(a)                                   # output  : [0, 1, 2, 3]
a = []
print([a.append(i) for i in range(0, 4)])  # output  : [None, None, None, None]
a = []
for i in range(0, 4): a.append(i)     
print(a)                                   # output  : [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What exactly you don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

`list.append()` modifies `list` in place and returns `None`, so if you use a REPL you can see this:

```py
>>> a = []
>>> [a.append(i) for i in range(4)]  # didn't assign to a variable, so prints result in REPL
[None, None, None, None]   # append returns None so get 4 of them.
>>> print(a)  # append modifies the list, so it has the value.
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

You should not use in-place actions in a list comprehension, just use:

```py
a = [x for x in range(4)]
```

or

```py
a = list(range(4))
```

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking, isn't because I'm trying to print a loop?, It's like trying to print many statements, I can't print the iteration (and the list comprehension is just that) , only the result of this. Maybe?

Comment: @Pablo A list comprehension computes a new list from an existing iterable and should be assigned to a variable.  What your original was doing was creating a list and throwing it away just for the `.append()` side effect.  In that case a `for` loop should be used.

Comment: Right, I get it now!!!, can I do something that it may not be allowed, a question about something else:

Comment: Mark, all right, I get it now!!!, can I do something that it may not be allowed? , a question about something else: i've got a value in (a), passes to (y) (y = a), and then (a) get another value for some calcul, but (y) changes too, I think It is called aliases, how can I break that?

Comment: It is inside a function and I need my " real" (a, y)